# Poker moving dealer chip

Tags: python, list, poker

I am making a poker game where I want to be able to customize the amount of players there are. I am trying to make a function that would move the dealer position  to the next player at the table. I have a list of player objects and each have the boolean is_dealer. In the function I  want to be able to make the boolean true for the next player on the list and make it false for the current player I am iterating through. My problem is that I don't know how to get the last player in the list to pass the position to the first player in the list.

```
    def move_positions(self):
    
    for people in range(number_of_players):

             if self.players[people].is_dealer==True:
                self.players[people].is_dealer= False
                self.players[people+1].is_dealer=True
```

players is my list of player objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that, instead of finding the current dealer each time you want to advance the dealer, you simply have a variable that keeps track of who the current dealer is. That being said, this snippet doesn't do that: It finds the current dealer, and then sets the next player to be the dealer, wrapping around if necessary:

```
def move_positions(self):

    dealer_index = next(index for index, player in enumerate(self.players) if player.is_dealer)
    self.players[dealer_index].is_dealer = False
    self.player[(dealer_index+1)%number_of_players].is_dealer = True
```

Comment: The technique to find the dealer index, although clever, is somewhat cryptic. Moreover, since player is not used, you should use an underscore as a placeholder. Upvoted anyway :-)

Comment: @Tarik Thanks for the upvote! However, `player` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Exit the loop as soon as you find the dealer. Handle the case where the last player is the dealer. Also, remove comparison operator with boolean.

```
for people in range(number_of_players):
     if self.players[people].is_dealer:
        self.players[people].is_dealer = False 
        self.players[(people+1)%number_of_players].is_dealer = True
        break
```